# Left over text annotations

Tags: qgis, annotation

I have an issue when trying to use the 'Save as image...' function in QGIS2.18

It always shows what I had earlier placed as text annotations. Even with all the layers turned off they still on the resultant jpg. I can't see the annotations anywhere, I deleted all the print composers in case they were being picked up there, but that didn't help.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but have you tried saving the project, reopening it and then printing?  It sounds like a bit of a bug and close-reopen dance should clear it hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

@MappaGnosis is right, it is a bug. I'd already tried the restart, bui that did not fix it, but have just tried copy of 2.14 I still had installed and loading the project in that I don't get the problem. I will report the issue to the QGIS team.